# OroCRM how to disable client side validation?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, orocrm

Can i disable client side validation (via jQuery) for specified field/constraint?

I tried this:
`form_widget(form.myField,{'attr':{'data-validation':''}})`

and it disabled both client side and backend validation. But i need to disable frontend validation only

Comment: This code can't disable backend validation.
What is the FormType used in this field ?

Comment: @HubertLcorche this is a text field

Comment: You can disable the "require validator" in your FormType class :

    $builder
            ->add('your_field', 'text', array('required' => false))
        ;

Comment: @HubertLcorche yes, i know about `'required'` param. But in OroCRM there is a jQuery Validator Plugin that get possibility to translate Symfony constraints to front-end (like regex, length and others constrains)

Comment: https://github.com/orocrm/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/FormBundle/Resources/doc/reference/js_validation.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to all of you. Today the Oro Core team developer Hryhorii Hrebiniuk provide a correct solution:

> So, if you want to remove all validation rule for the field with no
>   condition — you can use this approach. But there’s better approach.
>   Same as data-validation-optional-group attribute, there’s other useful
>   attribute — **data-validation-ignore**. If any field/group of fields is
>   wrapped in element with data-validation-ignore attribute, frontend
>   validator ignores validation rules for this field/group of fields. You
>   can add/remove this attribute in runtime to change validation
>   behavior.

OroCRM forum topic: http://www.orocrm.com/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-inherit-frontend-validation

For example:

```
{# this wrapper div disables front-end jQuery Validate validation #}

<div data-validation-ignore>
    {{ form_widget(form.field1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.field2) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.field3) }}
    ...
    {{ form_widget(form.fieldN) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To deactivate client side validation for all fields, try to use:

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'novalidate': ''} }) }}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked, thank you. And please look at my answer below - there is another way, provided by CRM vendor